# Is changing case with regular expression supported in editors other than Vim?

Tags: vim, regex

Today I had the need to change all url encoded strings like `%BF` to lower case ones like `%bf`. My first reaction is to write some Ruby scripts to do this conversion, and I began to consider use the `gsub` function like this `gsub(/%(\d|[ABCDEF]){2}/, '\1')` and then I realized that I can't  change the case of the back reference.

I wondered if I can change the case of back reference and googled. I find that [Vim has this ability](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions). Here's the command that can achieve my goal:

```
%s,%\(\d\|[ABCDEF]\)\{2},\L&,g
```

Here the `\L` prefix means change the matched text (specified by `&`) to lower case.

I'm just wondering if this feature is specific to Vim, or is it also supported by other editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other editors that support regular expression editing.  [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is another editor for Windows that supports regular expressions.  How widely supported they are I can't really answer.  I've got the 2 editors that I like (Vim and Notepad++) and stick with those.

Also, if any given editor has support for an add-in / extension framework then conceivably it will have support for regular expressions if / when an add-in is developed for it (if it doesn't natively have regex support already).